# Wildcard use on a range - Excel

Tags: excel

I am trying to run a comparison query between the data in two separate columns.  I need to find out if data in column A can be found in column D.  I am not looking for an exact match because the object naming conventions in column A were manually named where as column D were system named.  For example column A may be PL0051C0000_SH2 where as D will be 0051C0000.

Currently I am trying:

`HYPERLINK("#"&CELL("address",INDEX($D$2:$D$740,MATCH("*"&A2&"*",$D$2&"*":$D$740&"*"))),"Yes")`

But this is throwing me an error.

I think I am trying to do some sort of reverse lookup. The list in the A column contains larger strings like PL0051C0000_SH2 and I need the query to search within the D column to see if there is a partial match, for example 0051C0000. So essentially if any string in column D is contained in a string in column A, then put "Yes". Column A has about 24k rows where as D has 740.

What is the best way to use wildcard in an Excel data range?

Many thanks.

Comment: Not really.  I think I am trying to do some sort of reverse lookup.  The list in the A column contains larger strings like PL0051C0000_SH2 and I need the query to search within the D column to see if there is a partial match, for example 0051C0000.  So essentially if any string in column D is contained in a string in column A, then put "Yes".  Column A has about 24k rows where as D has 740.

Comment: It does answer your question, it's just that you probably want case insensitive search in which case you need to use `search` instead of `find`. Otherwise `=COUNT(INDEX(FIND($D$2:$D$740,A2),))` does exactly what you want. The only requirement is that there are no blank cells in `$D$2:$D$740`, and if there are, you must append `-COUNTBLANK($D$2:$D$740)`.

Comment: Mate, you are 100% spot on.  It works.  Thanks very much.